# Dropdown of nodes getting hidden in ngx-graph if I make the graph to display in fullscreen, any solution?options are being displayed behind fullscreen

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Actually I used fullscreen instead of regular fit to zoom option for ngx graph but when I go on fullscreen and click on node, related drop-down should display, but it's actually getting hidden, in other words, fullscreen is hiding the options, I need to drop-down to be displayed even when I am on fullscreen.

I tried with z- index and somehow it didn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.